# jQuery animate scrollTop

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, scrolltop

I have quite a few `section` tags in a div with an overflow set to `hidden`. The code is along the lines of this:

```
<div id="viewport">
   <section>
      content
   </section>
   <section>
      content
   </section>
</div>
```

I have it set up like this because I want to be able to scroll through the `sections` contained within the `div` when the corresponding link is pressed in the menu. I have this function:

```
$('#mn a').click(function(){
   var aHref = $(this).attr("href");
   var sectionHeight = $('section'+aHref+'').height();
   $('#viewport').height(sectionHeight);
});
```

Which I use to resize the `#viewport` div because the `sections` are different sizes. When I try to put this scroll part into that function:

```
$('body,html').animate({scrollTop: $(aHref).offset().top}, 800);
```

it makes the entire page scroll. When I try to replace `$('body,html')` with `$('section, #viewport')` it scrolls inside the div, but it doesn't do so properly.

I have a live example of this [here](http://andrewpeacock.tumblr.com/bernardiprofile). I assume it has something to do with either the `.offset()` or what I'm passing into the `.animate()`, but I've tried quite a few different things but to no avail. Can someone please point me in the right direction or tell me what I've done wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is how `position()` works, it returns top/height related to `scrollTop`.

So if you request at click `$('section'+aHref+'').position().top` the position returned is modified from `scrollTop` value.

You can get all height position at ready event. (so `scrollTop` is `0`)

Or you can sanitize position values with:

```
$("section#skills").position().top + $("#viewport").scrollTop()
```

Answer (score 8):

First of all you should prevent the default behavior of the anchor in order to scroll the page to the top of the page. You can do this by calling `preventDefault()` method on the event object inside `click` event handler. Try this

```
$('#mn a').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();

   var aHref = $(this).attr("href");
   var top = $('section'+aHref+'').position().top;
   $('#viewport').animate({scrollTop: top}, 800);
});
```

Comment: I had the `e.preventDefault()` in there, but I thought it was messing something up for some reason so I took it out. Unfortunately the solution you've proposed doesn't work either.

Comment: Can you alert `sectionHeight` and see what you get?

Comment: 255 for the first one. It makes it scroll back and forth, but never completely to the bottom.

Comment: I hosted it here: http://andrewpeacock.tumblr.com/testingscroll2 Right after loading, if I click on any of the links it works perfectly. After that it no longer works though.

Answer (score -1):

If you want a simple jquery plugin to do this then you can try ([AnimateScroll](http://plugins.compzets.com/animatescroll)) which currently supports more than 30 easing styles too